# Importing and filtering RSS feeds into nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking for the best way to import a feed, say BBC News and filter through all the content so only articles containing a keyword are stored in the database. I'd like each item to be shown as a node of a specific content type and for it to be updated every given time interval. Is there a straightforward way to do this? (I don't have much experience in php at all so be specific please)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import the nodes.

Use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module + Cron to run automated actions on your nodes.

I'm not sure how to filter out the content, but these two modules should get you started. TIP: It would almost better to have the content filtered before you import the nodes into Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

The [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) has the ability to create nodes from an RSS feed.  Once setup, it can run at regular intervals.

In addition the [Feeds Tamper module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) can help you filter based on keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Before going with the feeds module, be sure to review the project bugs list first (https://drupal.org/project/issues/feeds?categories=bug). This is not a very solid module. For example, feeds cannot update via cron, they have to be updated manually. This alone should be a showstopper for most folks.

I'm only talking about the D6 version.